# Cannot Convert value of type CGPoint

Tags: swift

**I am trying to move the object synchronously using swift socket programming.**
**strong text**

```
 func socketEvents() {

        socket?.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
            self.delegate?.didConnect()
        }

        socket?.on("drawing") { (data, ack) in
            guard let dataInfo = data.first else { return }
            if let response: SocketPosition = try? SocketParser.convert(data: dataInfo) {
                let position = CGPoint.init(x: response.x, y: response.y)
                self.delegate?.didReceive(point: position)
            }
        }
```

*self.delegate?.didReceive(point: position)-> (line just above) "Cannot convert value of type 'CGPoint' to expected argument type 'SocketPosition' I get an error"*

**This is a position model class**

```
struct SocketPosition: Codable
{
    
    var x: Double 
    var y: Double
   
}
```

**The element variable represents a declared UIView added to the screen. This UIView is receiving and CGPoint that uses the value from the SocketPosition.**

```
@IBOutlet weak var element: UIView!

func didReceive(point: SocketPosition){
        element.center = CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y)
       
    }
```

Comment: in the original post by João Gabriel, SocketPosition is a struct. https://medium.com/cocoaacademymag/real-time-client-server-communication-with-socket-io-4311a79b0553

Comment: yes, but some problem

Answer (score 1):

`didReceive` delegate method accepts `SocketPosition`, but you try to send a `CGPoint`